# Converting user entered location into something usable

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, bigdata

I have a table containing user entered location data, taken from a series of tweets. Here's an example:

```
texas 
Chicago
california
NEW YORK
Ohio
Canada
London
nyc
michigan
Tx
nj 
Florida
Chicago, IL
New Jersey 
Indiana
HTX
Los Angeles
Houston, TX
```

As you can see Texas appears four times in different forms.

Does anyone know a way of "normalising" the data to bring out city, state, country from what I have? Is there a pre-existing look-up database or api for example?

Happy for solutions in MySQL and/or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the end:

http://www.geonames.org/

Which will do what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Oh so i think you can use followed Mysql query

```
select DISTINCT Column from table where Column IN (select replace(Column, 'tx', 'texas') from table where Column like '%tx%')
```

I leave first answer as it is so it may help someone else.

Comment: This would work in that narrow case but not for every town, city and state worldwide.